# Can't remove grey space around header image on mobile?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

My knowledge is pretty limited but have tried playing around with inspect element and cannot seem to figure it out? Thanks in advance
[site link](https://www.acutherapymat.com/)

[image]

I am trying to achieve this..
[image]

#

**edit / update:** got it mostly working just trying to figure out how to get rid of these two, can I do it through additional css?

[image]

Comment: Please add the code to your question to make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Have you tried adding *{ margin: 0; padding: 0; } at the start of your file to reset values

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you. add this to your CSS styles:

```
    .header-filter {
    background-size: auto;
}
```

Comment: That does not work on desktop or mobile. On desktop it causes the image to repeat, on mobile it causes the image to not be contained width wise

Answer (score 0):

First, delete that `content: "";` in `header-filter::after`
second, add style to`page-header{ background-color: #ffffff}`.

The progress:


***I took the photo in a div itself and checked what's behind it (added `z-index` just to make sure it's on the top):***
[image]

**then I deleted the content:**

[image]

**Changed background-color to red:**

[image]

**The final results:**

[image]

Comment: just updated origional post, I am trying to get rid of the free space, so the image below flows on straight after

Answer (score 0):

Recode the `.header-filer @media`

[image]


Delete `padding` and `min-height`

[image]


The Results:

[image]

Comment: That's the one thankyou, just trying to work out how to delete padding & min-height in additional css. I have tried : 
.page-header  element.style {
    /* min-height: 667px; */
}

@media (max-width: 991px)
.carousel .page-header {
    /* padding: 0 30px; */